# How bad is it to 'delete and insert' as against using DataAdapter.Update in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, ado.net

I have developed a C# windows form with a DataGridView selecting data from a table with IDENTITY columns in SQL Server.

When the user clicks 'Save', after making changes to DataGridView, i am deleting all rows that were fetched, and inserting all rows from the DataGridView to the database. This creates a new set of IDENTITY columns. I may end up having 100,000 rows in this table. My worry is that at some point in the future the IDENTITY column may exceed it's limit.

On the other hand i find the additional code for DataAdapter.Update a bit daunting. That is why i preferred the above approach.

How bad a choice is it ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's very bad, for the reasons outlined below.

1. As you pointed out, you have a limited number of faux "Updates" to your table. Which will cause catastrophic failure at an undefined point in time. You could solve this by reseeding the table, but that's messy
2. Your network traffic/CPU consumption/memory consumption is A LOT larger than it could be, which may cause you to over resource your servers when you aren't updating bulk records
3. When performing deletes from SQL, any indexing will be fragmented. If you have any indexes on the table, over time they will become more and more useless. You could work around this by re-indexing frequently

In short, take the time now to build a robust solution. You won't regret it.

You could also look into an ORM, such as `EntityFramework`, which handles `Insert/Update/Delete` actions automatically.